# How can I define external css to reuse in wordpress post and page?

Tags: css, wordpress, post

I need to add text to a box in a WordPress post.So i want to define this css to reuse in other post. How can i do that ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution

put this css in your style sheet

```
.text-box{
width:auto;
background-color:#898989;
color:#fff;
height:120px;
border:1px #202020 solid;
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
border:radius:4px;
}
```

This is the code for your post. add this code in the text editor then change it what ever you want. `Your text here`

```
<div class="text-box">
Your text here
</div>
```